# SQLiteException: no such column when trying to update sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I tried to insert a new column in my database the same way I always do but for some unknown reason, there is a problem with another column which was working fine until I made the latest addition. Here is the error output:

```
SQLiteException: no such column: DistanceFromHotel (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE contents SET Longitude=?,WebsiteURL=?,Phone=?,PostalCode=?,Email=?,Latitude=?,MainImageURL=?,ID=?,DistanceFromHotel=?,OnlineBookingURL=? WHERE ID=77
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:896)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:507)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1604)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1552)
at com.hotelstayapp.android.utilities.Database.importContent(Database.java:443)
```

And here is where I try to communicate with the database and get the error:

```
public long importContent(ContentSync data){
        Long ret=null;
        Content content=new Content();

        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        if(data.IsDeleted){
            database.delete(TABLE_CONTENTS,"ID="+data.ID,null);
            return 1;
        } else {
            values.put("ID", data.ID);
            values.put("PostalCode", data.PostalCode);
            if(data.Latitude!=0){
                values.put("Latitude", data.Latitude);
            } else {
                values.putNull("Latitude");
            }

            if(data.Latitude!=0) {
                values.put("Longitude", data.Longitude);
            } else {
                values.putNull("Longitude");
            }

            values.put("Phone", data.Phone);
            values.put("Email", data.Email);
            values.put("WebsiteURL", data.WebsiteURL);
            values.put("OnlineBookingURL", data.OnlineBookingURL);
            values.put("MainImageURL", data.MainImage);
            values.put("DistanceFromHotel",data.DistanceFromHotel);

            if(isContentRecord(data.ID)){ //update
                ret=data.ID;
                database.update(TABLE_CONTENTS,values,"ID="+data.ID,null);
            } else {
                ret=database.insert(TABLE_CONTENTS,null,values);
            }

            return ret;
        }
    }
```

I pulled the database and checked it 5 times, the column exist. I read similar problems but I can't find a fix for my problem. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Here is the structure of the table I am trying to update:

[image]

Comment: Can you add your create table commands as well.

Comment: Plz add your table creation block of code.

Comment: I don't create the table, I made the database with SQLiteStudio and insert it in assets

Comment: @student We need to see the structure of the database to identify the problem. Please make at least a screenshot or generate `CREATE` query and copy it here.

Comment: Ok I uploaded the structure of the table.

Comment: do you mean are you made new version and trying to update old one?@student

Comment: as a side question, does it work with DistanceFromLocation?

Comment: @ChiragTalsaniya no I updated the old one. I added a new column to a different table!

Comment: It would be nice to show the upgrade of db code.

Comment: @student can you post ContentSync model?

Comment: @Student have you tried clearing the App's data (or uninstalling the App) *(if possible)*?  If you haven't specifically included code to amend the structure and are expecting `onCreate` (or an equivalent) to run and the database file hasn't been deleted, the structure will not change.